# How do I handle complex objects in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, web, reactjs, reactjs.net

I have the following `ReactJS` code :

```
var data1 = {"Columns":["Title1","Title2","Title3"],"Rows":[{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"CellText":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]}]};


var GridRow = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        if(this.props.data){

        }
        return (
            <div>Text</div>
        );
    }
});


var GridList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        if(this.props.data){
            var Header = this.props.data.Columns.map(function (columns) {
                return (
                    <GridRow data={columns}>
                );
            });
            var Row = this.props.data.Rows.map(function (rows) {
                return (
                    <GridRow data={rows}>
                );
            });
        }
        return (
            <ul>
                <li>{Header}</li>
                <li>{Row}</li>
            </ul>
        );
    }
});


var GridBox = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <GridList data={data1} />
        );
    }
});
```

I'm trying to pass the `data1` variable to the `GridList` where it is split up to `Columns` (for header) and rows. The problem is that I get the following exception at runtime:

> In file "~/Scripts/Grid.jsx": Parse Error: Line 30: Unexpected token
>   return (at line 30 column 6) Line: 52 Column:3

I'm running this from within Visual Studio 2013 with ReactJS.

The stated Line nr and colum makes no sense

Im trying to render a table based on metadata(columns) and row data from service.

Comment: Where does `Test` come from (in your `GridRow` class)?

Comment: Its nothing more then a string out to the HTML.

Comment: Yes, but it isn't defined in your example, could you add it?  That might help debug the issue :-)

Comment: Sorry but its just a simple string I have typed there, no variable at all. If I remove it I get this instead : In file "~/Scripts/Grid.jsx": Parse Error: Line 16: Unexpected token ; (at line 16 column 4)
Line: 52
Column:3 but there is no ; at line 16.

Comment: Try `return <div>Test</div>` instead of `return (Test);`

Comment: Done, I have updated the code above but I still get the same exception.

Comment: instead of mapping the data into the `Row` variable could you try mapping `this.props.data.Rows` into a variable: `this.props.data.Rows.map(function(row) { return <li><GridRow rowData={row} /></li>; })`

Comment: Im not sure what you mean? I have a var Row = Is it this variable you mean? Should I remove this and place the code you wrote direcly in the return?

Comment: @Ganonside I have no changed the code to what I think you meant. The exception are as you can see the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to close tags either with a matching closing tag, or using self closing tags.

```
// ERROR
<GridRow data={rows}>

// OK
<GridRow data={rows}></GridRow>

// Best
<GridRow data={rows} />
```

<sup>The error message isn't very helpful.</sup>

Also, when creating an array of nodes, it's good to give them keys.

```
Rows.map(function(row, i){
    return <GridRow data={rows} key={i} />;
});
```

---

I played around with it some more, and the weirdness comes from JSX accepting anything between an opening tag and `<`, `{`, or `}` as raw text.  If you did something like this:

```
var GridList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        if(this.props.data){
            var Header = this.props.data.Columns.map(function (columns) {
                return (
                    <GridRow data={columns}>
                );
            });
            var Row = this.props.data.Rows.map(function (rows) </GridRow>
            )});
        }
        return (
            <ul>
                <li>{Header}</li>
                <li>{Row}</li>
            </ul>
        );
    }
});
```

It'll happily output this:

```
var GridList = React.createClass({displayName: "GridList",
    render: function() {
        if(this.props.data){
            var Header = this.props.data.Columns.map(function (columns) {
                return (
                    React.createElement(GridRow, {data: columns}, 
                ");" + ' ' +
            "});" + ' ' +
            "var Row = this.props.data.Rows.map(function (rows) ")
            )});
        }
        return (
            React.createElement("ul", null, 
                React.createElement("li", null, Header), 
                React.createElement("li", null, Row)
            )
        );
    }
});
```

It's completely content until it encounters the `{` after `Rows.map(function (rows)`, which means "go back into JavaScript expression mode", and it encounters a `return` in an expression, which is invalid, so it bails, and gives the best error it can.